# How to handle different types of errors in Clean Architecture?

Tags: javascript, node.js, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

So, in the process of creating a user there are 4 possible outcomes:

1. Username is already taken
2. Email is already taken
3. Username is invalid
4. Email is invalid

Here is what I have in the controller for now:

```
  const user = await this.addUserService.add(username, email, password)

  if (user) {
    return {
      statusCode: 201,
      body: user
    }
  } else {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: // ???
    }
  }
```

The thing is, what should the `addUserService` return if the username/email is invalid or in use?

I am thinking about creating different error types, such as `InvalidParamsError`, `ParamInUseError` and share them between the `UserController` and `UserService`.

So I would have something like this:

```
  const result = await this.addUserService.add(username, email, password)

  if (result instanceof InvalidParamsError || result instanceof ParamInUseError) {
    return {
      statusCode: 401,
      body: result.message
    }
  } else { // then we assume user has been created
    return {
      statusCode: 201,
      body: 'User created!'
    }
  }
```

Is it okay to share these Error classes between the controller and the service? If not, or even if it's okay, is there a better way to handle errors when the outcome is not a simple `true` or `false`?

Thanks.

EDIT: Also, I just realized that the `UserRepository` checks if a username and/or email already exists. So I would have to share the `ParamInUseError` between three modules: `UserController`, `UserService` and `UserRepository`

Comment: Checking for a non-repeated username or email is not a repository responsibility. Just because it has the resources to do it, doesn't mean it's his responsibility. Somone consuming the repository will decide whether repeated emails and usernames are problematic and it will decide which error to propagate according to the needs.  the rest of the layers will translate these responses into their own model and responses too. And so on.

Comment: @Laiv that's right, thanks for reminding me! what's your take on the error handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning multiple types (subtypes) is a completely valid approach, in order to represent ok/error behaviour of a method. For statically typed languages, constructs like union type could be used, in JavaScript this is easier, since you can simply return any object from a method.

Instead of returning a success/error objects from a method, it's also possible to simply throw from an underlying layer, and let the exception bubble up to a place in your app where it's appropriately handled. This is however sometimes frowned upon, as it may lead to abusing exception to a point where they act as a control flow and basically a modern `goto`.

How much you want to propagate between layers depends entirely up to you and your architecture. Consider a system which would consist of two modules:

1. Money Account - allows you to make `DEPOSIT`, `WITHDRAWAL` and `PURCHASE` transactions,
2. Ticket - allows you to buy a ticket for money from your money account.

Now, when making a `WITHDRAWAL` or `PURCHASE` transaction, the money account module may return an error: `INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS`.

The process of purchasing a ticket consists of creating a valid ticket, which is preceded by successfully processing a `PURCHASE` transaction (i.e. purchasing a ticket may end due to the `INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS` error).

In this case you you have basically these two options:

1. fail the ticket purchase with the `INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS` error,
2. fail the ticket purchase with a new error, e.g. `PURCHASE_TRANSACTION_FAILED`, where you could/should also append an original error, which would point to `INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS`.

That way each module has its own set of granular errors, while still preserving the original error situation.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much! will do that

Answer (score -1):

According to R. Martin's "Clean Architecture" everything must have [a single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), meaning it has only one reason to change. This is strongly correlated with another principle of clean coding and software engineering - [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Therefore if we were to follow these principles, your presentation layer of your domain has to have a separate unit, isolated from other ones, which has one purpose - handle errors.

Comment: If you quote SRP as the single reason to change a design then you are wrong already. Find an _actual_ reason for a change. If your post says nothing but “clean architecture”, “single responsibility”, “one reason for change” and “separation of concerns” without explanation then I’m quite sure you don’t actually understand any of those terms.

Comment: First of all this information isn't hidden, nobody restricts from googling, SE isn't a Wikipedia if I didn't miss anything yet and if I am not mistaken this is even discouraged. Speaking of SRP, this you who has no idea what is this. You must have great insecurities if you compensating them with minusing of completely valid answers on the questions. I feel for you.

Comment: One day you will also understand the difference between people who know things and people who can quote keywords from a book. Information content of your post was zero.

Comment: Your answer could be improved in order  to be useful to the person asking the question. Right now, it is a collection of references with insufficient detail added to provide value. A good answer helps bridge any such references with the content of the question to help improve understanding.